# Prove that the problem MATCH is NP-complete

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, algorithm-analysis, np-complete, np-hard

The problem MATCHED is defined as follows: given an infinite set S of strings of arbitrary length over the alphabet {0, 1}, determine if there exists a character of length n over the alphabet {0, 1} such that for every string s ∈ S, s and w does not match.

My approach: TO prove MATCHED is in NP is easy. For NP Hard, I was trying to reduce SAT to MATCH in polynomial time where length of the set S is equal to the number of clauses in the boolean formula and number of literals in each clause equal to the string length. But, I am finding difficulty in showing the transformation of any boolean formula in CNF form to a set of strings in set S.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\phi = c_1 \wedge c_2 \wedge \dots c_m$ be a 3-SAT formula on $n$ variables $x_1, \dots, x_n$, where $c_i$ is the $i$-th clause.
Assume w.l.o.g. that no clause contains both a literal and its complement (these clauses are always true and can be removed).

The set $S$ contains one string $s_i$ of length $n$ for each clause $c_i$. The $j$-th symbol of $s_i$ is $0$ if $c_i$ contains $\overline{x_j}$ as a literal, it is $1$ if $c_j$ contains $x_j$ as a literal, and it is $*$ otherwise.

If there is a solution $w$ to the match instance, consider the truth assignment that sets $x_j$ to true iff the $j$-th symbol of $w$ is $1$. Since
each clause $c_i$ has at least one $0$ or $1$ in common with $w$, there is at least one negated literal for which the corresponding variable has been set to false, or one positive literal for which the corresponding variable has been set to true. Hence, all clauses of $\phi$ are satisfied.

If there a truth assignment that satisfies $\phi$, then define $w$ by letting the $j$-th symbol be $0$ if $x_j$ is set to false, and $1$ otherwise.
Each clause $c_i$ has at least one satisfied literal $\ell_i$, and this literal is either a positive variable $x_j$ that is set to true, or a negated variable $\overline{x}_j$ that is set to false. In the former case the $j$-th symbol of both $s_i$ and $w$ is $1$, in the latter it is $0$. Therefore $w$ is a solution for the match instance.